# spacing between lines

Tags: spacing

I am trying to compose a dictionary and I think I am getting close to finishing, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the spacing equal/even between the entries(see picture). As you will see on the left side of the picture the spacing seems larger than on some words from the right side. Thanks!

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino fontm

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5mm}

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns

\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\usepackage{datatool}


\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\newcommand{\entry}[5] {\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \ \textit{#2} \textbf{#3} \ \textit{#4}{ #5}} % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right


\begin{document}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   SECTION A
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{A}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\hangindent=3pt\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
        \raggedright
        
        \entry{abandon}{(v.)}{}{}{relinquō, relinquere, reliquisse, relictum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}
        
        \entry{ablative}{(gram.)}{}{}{ablātīvus} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        \entry{about}{(prep.)}{}{}{super } \textit{prep+abl.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{above}{(prep.)}{}{}{suprā} \textit{prep+acc} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{absent}{(adj.)}{}{}{absēns, absentis} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{abundance}{(subs.)}{}{}{cōpia, -ae} \textit{f.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{abyss}{(subs.)}{}{}{vorāgō, vorāginis} \textit{f.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{accidentally}{(adv.)}{}{by chance}{forte} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{accompany}{(v.)}{}{}{comitor, comitārī, comitātum esse} \textit{v. dep.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{accomplish}{(v.)}{}{make, manufacture}{conficiō, conficere, confēcisse, confectum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{accusative}{(gram.)}{}{}{accūsātīvus} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{accuse}{(v.)}{}{}{accūsāre} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{acknowledge}{(v.)}{}{}{fateor, fatērī, fassum esse} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{across}{(prep.)}{}{}{trāns} \textit{prep + acc.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{active }{(adj.)}{}{energetic}{impiger, impigra, impigrum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{active voice}{(gram.)}{}{}{vōx āctīva} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{add}{(v.)}{I. 1.}{}{addō, addere, addidisse,  additum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{2.} \ {adiciō, adicere, adiēcisse, adiectum}\textit{with dat or with ad + acc}{}{} \textbf{II. 1} \ \textit{add to, join} \ {adiungō, adiungere, adiunxisse, adiunctum} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{address}{(v.)}{}{call}{appellāre} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{adjective}{(gram.)}{}{}{adiectīvum, -ī} \textit{n.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{admiration}{(subs.)}{}{}{admīrātiō, admirātiōnis} \textit{f.} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
        
        \entry{admit }{(v.)}{}{to allow to enter}{admittō, admittere, admīsisse, admissum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \ {}{}{}\textbf{} \textit {} \ {} \ {}{}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ {}\textbf{} \textit{} \ {} \ \textit{} \textbf{} \ \textit{} \ {} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {} {} \ {}\\
            
                \end{multicols}
                    \end{flushleft}
                
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: unrelated but the comment here is wrong `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters` utf8x is a non standard option, it is better to stick to the standard utf-8 support unless you specifically need a fratire provided by utf8x

Comment: why have you got markup like `{vōx āctīva} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{} \ {}\textit{}{}{} \textbf{} ` ?  the `\textbf{}` and `\textit{}` don't change any font as the argument is empty but this forces a weird space of 9 normal inter-word spaces?  if `a b` has one space between a and b, the `a \textit{} \ \textit{} \ b` has 5 spaces between a and b???

Comment: I've created this data base (about 2000 words) originally in excel so I just created an algorithm to have the formatting (italics, bolding, etc) import into latex...Not sure if that was the best way to do it though! Would like to know if there is an easier/more effective way to do it.  Thanks for seeing my comment!

Comment: latex can format them, but if you explicitly force it to add multiple spurious spaces then it will do that and it's hard to say what to do other than don't do that.  Your question basically is asking why `one two` and `three \ \ {} \ \ {} four` have inconsistent space. The answer is that the second form forces 7 spaces between the words, where  the first form has one.

Comment: @David Carlisle The OP is asking about spaces between entries. Like between add and address.

Comment: @SimonDispa yes I had assumed that from the title, but the inter-word spacing was so disturbing It seemed better to address that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all the inter-word spacing and made `\entry` start a new paragraph so that you get the same space vertical whether or not there is a blank line in the source. Related to that I removed all the `\\` . the `\entry` command only seems to cope with a word with a single entry, the multiple clases for **add* seem to be done "by hand" I left it that way as I wasn't sure what the various clauses and font changes indicated although it would be better to have an extended versuon of `\entry` that coped directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings


\usepackage[english]{babel}
% no \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino fontm

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5mm}

% already loaded above \usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns

\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
% not used here \usepackage{datatool}


\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\newcommand\useifnotempty[2]{\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\ #1{#2}\fi}

% Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right
\newcommand{\entry}[5]{%
\par\smallskip
\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \textit{#2}%
\useifnotempty\textbf{#3}%
\useifnotempty\textit{#4}%
\useifnotempty{}{#5}} 


\begin{document}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   SECTION A
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{A}
% use the \raggedright below \begin{flushleft}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\hangindent=3pt\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
        \raggedright
        
        \entry{abandon}{(v.)}{}{}{relinquō, relinquere, reliquisse, relictum}
        
        \entry{ablative}{(gram.)}{}{}{ablātīvus}
        \entry{about}{(prep.)}{}{}{super } \textit{prep+abl.}
        
        \entry{above}{(prep.)}{}{}{suprā} \textit{prep+acc}
        
        \entry{absent}{(adj.)}{}{}{absēns, absentis}
        
        \entry{abundance}{(subs.)}{}{}{cōpia, -ae} \textit{f.}
        
        \entry{abyss}{(subs.)}{}{}{vorāgō, vorāginis} \textit{f.}
        
        \entry{accidentally}{(adv.)}{}{by chance}{forte}
        
        \entry{accompany}{(v.)}{}{}{comitor, comitārī, comitātum esse} \textit{v. dep.}
        
        \entry{accomplish}{(v.)}{}{make, manufacture}{conficiō, conficere, confēcisse, confectum}        
        \entry{accusative}{(gram.)}{}{}{accūsātīvus}        
        \entry{accuse}{(v.)}{}{}{accūsāre}
        
        \entry{acknowledge}{(v.)}{}{}{fateor, fatērī, fassum esse}
        
        \entry{across}{(prep.)}{}{}{trāns} \textit{prep + acc.}
        
        \entry{active}{(adj.)}{}{energetic}{impiger, impigra, impigrum}
        
        \entry{active voice}{(gram.)}{}{}{vōx āctīva}
        
        \entry{add}{(v.)}{I. 1.}{}{addō, addere, addidisse,  additum}\quad\textbf{2.}  {adiciō, adicere, adiēcisse, adiectum} \textit{with dat or with ad + acc}\quad \textbf{II. 1}  \textit{add to, join}  {adiungō, adiungere, adiunxisse, adiunctum}
        
        \entry{address}{(v.)}{}{call}{appellāre}
        
        \entry{adjective}{(gram.)}{}{}{adiectīvum, -ī} \textit{n.}
        
        \entry{admiration}{(subs.)}{}{}{admīrātiō, admirātiōnis} \textit{f.}
        
        \entry{admit}{(v.)}{}{to allow to enter}{admittō, admittere, admīsisse, admissum}
            
                \end{multicols}
%                    \end{flushleft}
                
        \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I think those extra space at the end of each entry is responsible for the trouble.

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino fontm
\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5mm}

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns

\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\usepackage{datatool}


\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\newcommand{\entry}[5]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \ \textit{#2} \textbf{#3} \ \textit{#4}{#5}} % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right

\begin{document}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   SECTION A
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{A}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{multicols}{2}\hangindent=3pt\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
        \raggedright
        
        \entry{abandon}{(v.)}{}{}{relinquō, relinquere, reliquisse, relictum}\bigskip
        
        \entry{ablative}{(gram.)}{}{}{ablātīvus}\bigskip
        
        \entry{about}{(prep.)}{}{}{super } \textit{prep+abl.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{above}{(prep.)}{}{}{suprā} \textit{prep+acc}\bigskip
        
        \entry{absent}{(adj.)}{}{}{absēns, absentis}\bigskip
        
        \entry{abundance}{(subs.)}{}{}{cōpia, -ae} \textit{f.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{abyss}{(subs.)}{}{}{vorāgō, vorāginis} \textit{f.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{accidentally}{(adv.)}{}{by chance}{forte}\bigskip
        
        \entry{accompany}{(v.)}{}{}{comitor, comitārī, comitātum esse} \textit{v. dep.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{accomplish}{(v.)}{}{make, manufacture}{conficiō, conficere, confēcisse, confectum}\bigskip
        
        \entry{accusative}{(gram.)}{}{}{accūsātīvus}\bigskip
        
        \entry{accuse}{(v.)}{}{}{accūsāre}\bigskip
        
        \entry{acknowledge}{(v.)}{}{}{fateor, fatērī, fassum esse}\bigskip
        
        \entry{across}{(prep.)}{}{}{trāns} \textit{prep + acc.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{active}{(adj.)}{}{energetic}{impiger, impigra, impigrum}\bigskip
        
        \entry{active voice}{(gram.)}{}{}{vōx āctīva}\bigskip

        \entry{add}{(v.)}{I. 1.}{}{addō, addere, addidisse,  additum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{2.} \ {adiciō, adicere, adiēcisse, adiectum}\textit{with dat or with ad + acc}{}{} \textbf{II. 1} \ \textit{add to, join} \ {adiungō, adiungere, adiunxisse, adiunctum}\bigskip
        
        \entry{address}{(v.)}{}{call}{appellāre}\bigskip
        
        \entry{adjective}{(gram.)}{}{}{adiectīvum, -ī} \textit{n.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{admiration}{(subs.)}{}{}{admīrātiō, admirātiōnis} \textit{f.}\bigskip
        
        \entry{admit }{(v.)}{}{to allow to enter}{admittō, admittere, admīsisse, admissum}\bigskip
            
                \end{multicols}
                    \end{flushleft}
                
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why `additum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{2.` which is just a weird way of forcing 5 spaces before the 2 ???

Comment: I can remove the extra \ for eliminate extra spaces

Answer (score 1):

I simplify the entries (now each entry starts a new paragraph) and added `\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}` to control their separation.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article} % 10pt font size, A4 paper and two-sided margins

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino fontm

\usepackage{microtype} % Improves spacing
\usepackage{multicol}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5mm}

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for splitting text into multiple columns

\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec} % Required for modifying section titles - bold, sans-serif, centered

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for modifying headers and footers
\usepackage{datatool}


\fancyhead[L]{\textsf{\rightmark}} % Top left header
\fancyhead[R]{\textsf{\leftmark}} % Top right header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the header
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}} % Bottom center footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt} % Rule under the footer
\pagestyle{fancy} % Use the custom headers and footers throughout the document
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\textsc{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\textsc{\leftmark}}

\newcommand{\entry}[5] {\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \ \textit{#2} \textbf{#3} \ \textit{#4}{ #5}} % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right

\begin{document}
    
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   SECTION A
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{A}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{multicols}{2}\hangindent=3pt\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}
            
            \setlength{\parskip}{1ex} % added <<<<<<
            \raggedright
            
            \entry{abandon}{(v.)}{}{}{relinquō, relinquere, reliquisse, relictum} 
            
            \entry{ablative}{(gram.)}{}{}{ablātīvus} 
            
            \entry{about}{(prep.)}{}{}{super } \textit{prep+abl.} 
            
            \entry{above}{(prep.)}{}{}{suprā} \textit{prep+acc}
            
            \entry{absent}{(adj.)}{}{}{absēns, absentis}
            
            \entry{abundance}{(subs.)}{}{}{cōpia, -ae} \textit{f.} 
            
            \entry{abyss}{(subs.)}{}{}{vorāgō, vorāginis} \textit{f.} 
            
            \entry{accidentally}{(adv.)}{}{by chance}{forte} 
            
            \entry{accompany}{(v.)}{}{}{comitor, comitārī, comitātum esse} \textit{v. dep.}
            
            \entry{accomplish}{(v.)}{}{make, manufacture}{conficiō, conficere, confēcisse, confectum} 
            
            \entry{accusative}{(gram.)}{}{}{accūsātīvus}
            
            \entry{accuse}{(v.)}{}{}{accūsāre}
            
            \entry{acknowledge}{(v.)}{}{}{fateor, fatērī, fassum esse}
            
            \entry{across}{(prep.)}{}{}{trāns} \textit{prep + acc.} 
            
            \entry{active }{(adj.)}{}{energetic}{impiger, impigra, impigrum} 
            
            \entry{active voice}{(gram.)}{}{}{vōx āctīva} 
            
            \entry{add}{(v.)}{I. 1.}{}{addō, addere, addidisse,  additum} \textit{} \ {} \ \textbf{2.} \ {adiciō, adicere, adiēcisse, adiectum}\textit{with dat or with ad + acc}{}{} \textbf{II. 1} \ \textit{add to, join} \ {adiungō, adiungere, adiunxisse, adiunctum }             
        
            \entry{address}{(v.)}{}{call}{appellāre} 
            
            \entry{adjective}{(gram.)}{}{}{adiectīvum, -ī} \textit{n.} 
            
            \entry{admiration}{(subs.)}{}{}{admīrātiō, admirātiōnis} \textit{f.} 
            
            \entry{admit }{(v.)}{}{to allow to enter}{admittō, admittere, admīsisse, admissum} 
            
        \end{multicols}
    \end{flushleft}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: why still double word spaces in the definition of `\entry` (`} \ `) ? if `#3` and `#4` are empty then `} \textbf{#3} \ \textit{#4}{ #` puts 4!! spaces between `#2` and `#5`

Comment: Great!  I have eliminated the extra spaces so it looks like this: \newcommand{\entry}[5] {\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} \textit{#2} \textbf{#3}\textit{#4}{ #5}} % Defines the command to print each word on the page, \markboth{}{} prints the first word on the page in the top left header and the last word in the top right

Comment: I did try to make all the formatting commands under \newcommand{\entry[40] etc.. with {#6} all the way to {#40}, but it would give me an error every time I passed number #5